# Smooth scroll: Avoid items with "display: none;" attribute

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to avoid items with a certain css-style, in my example "display: none;" while using smooth scroll?

Here is the script I am using:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('a[href*=\\#]').click(function() 
{
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
    || location.hostname == this.hostname) 
{   

  var target = jQuery(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : jQuery('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top + -10
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

Comment: How do you mean 'avoid items'? Can you also post relevant html?

Comment: By avoid I mean: scroll only to items which are visible. Because I use Isotope filtering, which hides certain items. I will post my code asap.

Comment: I opened another question (with relevant html, js, etc.) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670014/isotope-filters-in-combination-with-smooth-scroll
because I think the task I am asking for is a bit more complex than I thought.